# How to get into Dart Docker container's shell?

Tags: docker, shell, dart, docker-compose, sh

I'm trying to access the my [Dart Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/dart?tab=description) container's shell

```
$ docker-compose exec dartserver sh
```

but I'm getting this error message:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Any idea?

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM dart:stable AS build

# Resolve app dependencies.
WORKDIR /app
COPY pubspec.* ./
RUN dart pub get

# Copy app source code (except anything in .dockerignore) and AOT compile app.
COPY . .
RUN dart compile exe bin/server.dart -o bin/server

# Build minimal serving image from AOT-compiled `/server`
# and the pre-built AOT-runtime in the `/runtime/` directory of the base image.
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /runtime/ /
COPY --from=build /app/bin/server /app/bin/

# Start server.
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/app/bin/server"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scratch` image default don't have `shell` in it. If you really want to access shell, what I suggest is to use [busybox image](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox?tab=description).

See `busybox` [dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/blob/ecf0f5ecd9697ac16b9662679511bd5e011d34b4/unstable/uclibc/Dockerfile):

```
FROM scratch
ADD busybox.tar.xz /
CMD ["sh"]
```

It's also based on scratch, but with shell enable, additionally it's still very small.

Comment: Where do you get the busybox.tar.xz from? I'm getting file does not exist with the ADD command.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/tree/ecf0f5ecd9697ac16b9662679511bd5e011d34b4/unstable/uclibc